# Transforming a table from long format to wide format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table, union

I  have a question about union in SQL.

I have this type of table in long-format.

| id | value | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67 | users |
| 2 | 42 | users |
| 1 | 45 | politics |
| 2 | 89 | politics |

The code should yield something like this (i.e. a table in wide-format):

| id | users | politics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67 | 45 |
| 2 | 42 | 89 |

Is this possible to achieve by SQL?

Comment: For MariaDB, see See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670844/1766831

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `union`.  You want to pivot the data.  One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'users' then value end) as users,
       max(case when key = 'politics' then value end) as politics
from t
group by id;
```